# Login Url changing while Authentication - SmugMug API

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to authenticate & add SmugMug account to my application but during browser navigation login Url is changing.

Regular login Url i'm getting at start like below

```
https://api.smugmug.com/services/oauth/authorize.mg?Access=Full&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=xxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=xxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxxxx&oauth_version=1.0&Permissions=Modify&oauth_signature=xxxxxx
```

But after few seconds this Url is change like below

```
https://secure.smugmug.com/login?goTo=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.smugmug.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Fauthorize.mg%3FAccess%3DFull%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxx%26oauth_nonce%xxxx%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3Dxxxxx%26oauth_token%3Dxxxx%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26Permissions%3DModify%26oauth_signature%3Dxxxxx3D&noThirdPartyLogin=1&showSignUpButton=true&user=&oauthLogin=1&Ureferrer=0&code=0&oauth_token=xxxxx&Access=Full&Permissions=Modify
```

Here i can see some extra parameters have been added to this url like "noThirdPartyLogin","showSignUpButton","oauthLogin","Ureferrer","code". I didn't understand from where these all came.

I'm still getting login screen of SmugMug but redirect Url is not working and by this url app is redirect to-  https://xxxxxxx.smugmug.com/
I have tried to direct put first url to browser and found that url is still navigating and hence changed to new url.

This is used to work before but since 1-2 days its changing. How can i do this by first login url, any pointers on this is much appreciated.